# How to do multiple return in R function and combine the return in to table?

Tags: r, function, datatable, return

```
x <- function(beta){
  q <- numeric()
  e <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:10){
    q[i] <- i+2-beta
    e[i] <- i*3+beta
  }
  z <- mean(q)
  c <- sd(e)
  return(c)
  return(z)
}
x(3)
x(4)
x(7)
```

I want to have the return for both `c` and `z`, and combine all `x()` into a table such that the first column is `x(1)`,`x(4)`,`x(7)` and the second column is the values for `c` and the third column is the values for `z` . How should I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Return a `list`

```
x <- function(beta){
  q <- numeric(10)
  e <- numeric(10)
  for (i in 1:10){
    q[i] <- i+2-beta
    e[i] <- i*3+beta
   }
  list(mean = mean(q), sd = sd(e))
}

num <- c(1, 4, 7)
cbind.data.frame(x = num, t(sapply(num, x)))

#  x mean       sd
#1 1  6.5 9.082951
#2 4  3.5 9.082951
#3 7  0.5 9.082951
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your return values are scalars, you can use `c` for the return of `x` (otherwise, use `list`, as mentioned by @Ronak Shah), e.g.,

```
x <- Vectorize(function(beta){
  q <- numeric()
  e <- numeric()
  for (i in 1:10){
    q[i] <- i+2-beta
    e[i] <- i*3+beta
  }
  c(beta = beta, mean = mean(q), sd = sd(e))
})
```

where `Vectorize` is applied to allow vectorized operation of `x`.

**Example**

```
b <- c(1, 4, 7)
res <-as.data.frame(t(x(b)))

> res
  beta mean       sd
1    1  6.5 9.082951
2    4  3.5 9.082951
3    7  0.5 9.082951
```